# PDO does not return error even when setting error mode

Tags: php, pdo

EDIT: The problem is that the errors are not being displayed. This is just to clarify everyting.

I just learned what a PDO is, and I decided to test how it works. From the tutorials I've checked, you have to use the following line to display errors: `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`
So anyways, I used this line, made sure that my query had an error and it still didn't display any errors. The connection to the database works, it always returned me an error when it couldn't connect. Anyways, here my code:

```
<?php

// Connection to the mysql database using PDO

$mysql_host = "hidden";
$mysql_dbname = "hidden";
$mysql_username = "hidden";
$mysql_password = "hidden";

try {
 $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
 $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $DBH->prepare("SELECT username FROM username");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo "Error connecting to the database:" . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain clearly what is the problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: Preparing is not the same as executing a query. Your error might only show up on execution?

Comment: [AFAIK **`use`** and **`blob`** are reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Errors are not being flagged

Comment: @JamesWalsh, please, show your output.

Comment: @sectus None, that's the output

Comment: @JamesWalsh, turn on error output or search it in error.log of your server

Comment: @sectus The error output was not being displayed, but thanks to starless' answer, it worked. The tutorial I was looking at seemed to be unclear about errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get any errors because

```
$DBH->prepare("DELETE use FROM blob");
```

doesn't execute, only prepares a query to be executed.

Replace that line of code with:

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("DELETE use FROM blob");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Works! I dont know why, in the tutorial they just used prepare and said it should show an error :L. I think I'll change the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute it

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("DELETE use FROM blob");
$stmt->execute();
```

Otherwise it doesn't actually run the query.